# As of June 12th, are there any restrictions on who can enter Turkey or who has to undergo a 14-day quarantine?

Tags: turkey, covid-19

[According to IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm):

> 1. Coronavirus (COVID-19) entry regulations lifted on 12 June 2020.
> 2. Passengers and airline crew are subject to medical screening.

Does this mean that anyone (with a visa or visa-free passport) can now enter Turkey and not undergo a quarantine?

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR Turkey is opening borders but travellers must have a HES code

This is newly the case.

(Information retrieved from the [US embassy in Turkey](https://tr.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information-2/) as it was updated recently and in English).

> On June 11, Turkey announced opening the majority of its international air, land, and sea borders. The border with Iran remains closed.

Flights are starting to resume to Turkey. To enter Turkey all travelers must have a HES code (Hayat Eve Sığar) for domestic and international flights, train and ferry travel. This can be obtained [here](https://hayatevesigar.saglik.gov.tr/hes.html).

Comment: These are the old rules that were posted back in May. Did something change on June 12th?

Comment: @JonathanReez Hmm... not sure, the page I linked to what updated 12th June...

Comment: That link is now updated. Maybe you could update your answer?

Comment: @JonathanReez done, anything I missed?